# Phonegap Media plugin/code that styles like HTML5 <audio> and plays multiple mp3's needed

Tags: cordova

Has anybody seen source code or a plugin for phonegap Media object that styles in web page like the HTML5 'AUDIO' tag with controls. I have an app that needs the ability to play multiple MP3's from URL's in the same page. We are building the web page dynamically from data. I have looked and have not seen anything close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop reading my mind! Okay seriously I'm working on exactly that functionality in my Corinthian side project. Check it out. It is still in early stages but it'll get there, also feel free to contribute.

http://macdonst.github.com/corinthian/

Comment: Simon I downloaded your zip file form the the site.I imported your project into intellij ide. I was not able to build the jar, too many missing pieces. Can you provide the jar? Do images also have to be included, Cordova?

Comment: Yeah, just email me at my name @ gmail.com and I'll send you the jar. It is in early stages right now so building instructions aren't fully fleshed out. Yes, you need the images as I do a DOM replacement of the audio tag with a div. Actually if you just need the audio piece take a look at the corinthian.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Your app might be sent to suspended mode while switching songs in background if you use HTML5 audio.

There is a simple phonegap plugin I wrote (no UI though), that you can find here - https://github.com/vadimf/phonegap-audio-payer